# using fstream to write vector of types

Tags: c++, vector, sfml, fstream

I'm trying to write my vector of *chunks* which contains vectors of *Tile*s. It seems something is off with writing the correct value. Although it should have 25000 Tile objects, the size of the file is 4 bytes...

**world.cpp**

```
Tile tile;

for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 500; y++)
    {
        tile.setCoord(sf::Vector2i(x, y));
        tile.setBiome(0);
        chunk.push_back(tile);
    }
}
world.push_back(chunk);

ofstream file("saves/map.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
size_t s = world.size() * (chunk.size() * sizeof(Tile));
file.write((char *) &world, sizeof(s));
file.close();
```

**world.hpp**

```
class World {
public:
    // World getters
    int getTileSize() { return tileSize; };
    int getWorldSize() { return (width * tileSize) * (height * tileSize); };

    void load(const sf::String& filename);
    void save(const sf::String& filename);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, float dt);

    World(sf::Clock clock); // new
    World(const sf::String& filename, sf::Clock clock); // load

    ~World();

private:
    const int chunkSize = 64;

    int tileSize = 32; //default 32
    int width, height;
    std::vector<Tile> chunk;
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> world;

    sf::Clock clock;
};
```

If needed, here is the tile class:

```
class Tile {
public:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states);

    Tile();
    Tile(sf::Vector2i coord, int biome);
    ~Tile();

    sf::Vector2i getCoord() { return coord; };
    int getBiome() { return biome; };

    void setCoord(sf::Vector2i coord) { this->coord = coord; };
    void setBiome(int biome) { this->biome = biome; };

private:
    sf::Vector2i coord;
    int biome;
};
```

I've checked that the variable going into the writing is indeed filled with all the objects. So the problem is in the writing process, but I have no clue as to where...

Comment: Writing from the address `&world` will write the contents of the vector object and a lot of whatever is after it in memory. You can't write it all in one shot because each vector has a separate allocation and you have a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file.write((char *) &world, sizeof(s));
```

This won't work, for a couple of reasons.

First off, `sizeof(s)` is generally only going to be 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your compiler and what bitness you're targeting).  I assume you meant for that to just be `s`.

Even if you used `s` instead of `sizeof(s)` for the length of the data to write, `sizeof(std::vector)` is usually only 12 or 24 bytes (size, capacity, and a pointer to the data).  There simply aren't `s` bytes there to write.

Your data isn't a flat structure, so you're not going to be able to write it all in one go.  Look into serialization.  There are a number of libraries that exist to help solve this problem, such as [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [google protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), but you don't necessarily have to use a library.  You just need to come up with a structure that you can use to write your data and retain enough information to re-create your data structures later.

Comment: So for example if I chose not to pass the `&world` variable, but loop through it. Then instead of setting the `size_t` to a not working value, I could use `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(sf::Vector2i)` (which contains 2 ints, always)? Or is it a must to look into serializiation, as I have never used it before?

Comment: `file.write((char *) &coord, sizeof(sf::Vector2i));`